# Attempting to use the forward class 'EKCalendarItem' as superclass of 'EKEvent' when building to device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, eventkit

I have an iOS project that uses React Native and the [React Native Calendar Reminders](http://React%20Native%20Calendar%20Reminders) native module. When in Xcode and building to the simulator everything works fine. When changing it to build to "Generic iOS Device" I get the following error:

```
While building module 'EventKit' imported from .../RNCalendarReminders.m:3:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/Headers/EventKit.h:20:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/Headers/EKEvent.h:37:22: error: attempting to use the forward class 'EKCalendarItem' as superclass of 'EKEvent'
@interface EKEvent : EKCalendarItem {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^
```

`RNCalendarReminders.m` line 3 is:

```
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>
```

And I verified that in the Target's Build Phases it links with `EventKit.framework` library.

Xcode version: 8.2.1 (8C1002)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue myself. I'm not sure how but `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/Headers/EKCalendarItem.h` was an empty file. I may have accidentally cleared it out when looking at in Xcode at some point.

I re-downloaded Xcode and it resolved the issue.

The reason this worked fine when building on the simulator is because in that case `EventKit.framework` is a binary read from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework`.